# 'has_one :through' association using namespaced classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to use an `has_one :through` association using namespaced classes. I read the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) about association models but I don't know how to accomplish that.

I have `User`, `Relationship` and `Group`classes and **I would like to associate `Users` and `Groups` through the `Relationship` class**. As well, I would like to autosave related records and delete the relationship records on group or user deletion.

My file system is:

```
app/models/users/user.rb
app/models/users/relationship.rb
app/models/users/group.rb
```

In `configs/routes.rb` I have

```
namespace :users do
  resources :users
  resources :relationship
  resources :groups
end
```

Class (Model) statements are:

```
class Users::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Users::Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Users::Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

**How I must write code associations in above model files? Have you some advice about?**

---

**UPDATE**

My Classes (Models) have these attributes:

**User**

id

full_name

...

**Relationship**

id

user_id

group_id

**Group**

id

name

Comment: Your tables look fine, it should work with this setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route namespacing has nothing to do with your model namespacing.

```
class Users::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships, :class_name=>"Users::Relationship", :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
  has_many :groups, :class_name=>"Users::Group", :through=>:relationships
end

class Users::Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name=>"Users::User"
  belongs_to :group, :class_name=>"Users::Group"
end

class Users::Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationsips, :class_name=>"Users::Relationship", :dependent=>:destroy, :autosave=>true
end
```